# Simulate :page_down in Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

trying to simulate page-scroll (i want to scroll down on the instagram followers box, but let's try a easier example).

```
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.navigate.to "https://www.google.de/intl/de/policies/privacy/?fg=1"
browser.action.key_down :page_down
```

i do expect the page is scrolling down, but it isn't. I also tried o get the body element and then perform action on that element, not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll the page with a piece of JavaScript. Here is an example that scrolls down to the page:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

driver.navigate.to "https://www.instagram.com/barackobama/"

# scroll the height
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java scripts to scroll down page:

Create code in Ruby like mentioned in below links for java:

[Click here](http://www.360logica.com/blog/2016/02/multiple-ways-to-scroll-a-page-using-selenium-webdriver.html)

Comment: i fixed it. just had to "perform" an action

Answer (score 0):

i found out, i need to perform a action...

```
.key_down(:page_down).perform
```

that will fix it.

Comment: i fixed it. just had to "perform" an action